# C# and VBScript Interoperability - Forms

Tags: c#, vbscript, interop, winforms-interop

I am essentially trying to call a C# form from a vbscript. I have been able to get the interoperability to work on non-forms. The following works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using InteropTestingForm;

[assembly:System.CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly:Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa3")]


namespace InteropTesting
{
    [Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa3")]
    public class TestReply
    {
        public string salutation;
        public string name;
        public string time;
    }

    [Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa4")]
    public class TestObj
    {
        public TestObj() { }

        public TestReply SayHello(string addressee)
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(Form1());


            return SayHello(addressee, "hello");
        }

        public TestReply SayHello(string addressee, string greeting)
        {
            string x = String.Format("{0}, {1}!", greeting, addressee);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);

            TestReply r = new TestReply
            {
                salutation = greeting,
                name = addressee,
                time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("u")
            };
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen in my SayHello() function, I want to run another form, possibly in the same namespace. I am not sure how to accomplish this. I keep getting the following error: "The type or namespace name Form1() could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)? when I try to run the following command from a Visual Studio command prompt:

> csc.exe /t:library /debug+ /keyfile:InteropTesting.snk /out:InteropTesting.dll TestObj.cs